# Most important tips to protect an external drive on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, security, external-disk

Without taking information security tips in general, such as backups, what are some important tips and precautions to protect an external drive when using a Mac?

Answer (score 2):

Tip 1: Use APFS. This is more robust than HFS+ and so gives you some protection in cases of sudden disconnection. The file system should recover cleanly, though the content of files being written may be corrupt.

Tip 2: Avoid unplanned / premature disconnects. If physical disconnection is needed (e.g. for moving a laptop) make sure it is ejected and pause a few seconds to allow macOS and the device to write any data in progress.

Tip 3: Encrypt the drive as mitigation for the risk of theft. This is most easily done by using Disk Utility and encrypting when creating volumes.

Comment: I disagree with the second tip and even consider it potentially dangerous. As I described in my post, the current version of the system has a bug that causes some external drives (even formatted in APFS, as in my case) to fail on shutdown/reboot. So **my advice is to physically disconnect the drive before doing so**.

Comment: I've edited the answer - unplanned / premature disconnects are the cause of data failures and not hardware failures. @TimofeySuyargulov

Comment: @bmike, thanks. I agree that unplanned disconnections are the cause. However, I wasn't referring to disconnecting the drive because of hardware issues. The point is that in my case, even a drive that has already been ejected is relaunched when the system shuts down and disconnected abruptly by the system right away. I cannot determine the root of the problem, but I assume that some other users may be experiencing the same issue.

Answer (score -5):

### Tip: Never keep your drive plugged in while shutting down/rebooting the system

Before you shut down your Mac or go into hibernation mode, **be always sure to physically disconnect your drive**. This tip is caused by an existing bug in a current version of macOS (13.3.1) that can cause the drive to fail when shutting down/rebooting the Mac.

With my drive personally, it happened every time I shut down/rebooted my Mac. One day this led to the situation where the disk had to be reformatted.

Other users have also encountered this issue. Feedback (read in the comments section): https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695361

**Note!** Unplug your drive properly: eject it if it is not already ejected before pulling the cable out (notice that if you pull the cable out too slowly, it may cause the drive to reconnect when unplugging, which will result in a drive failure as well).

Some details in my case:

- Toshiba Canvio Basics 1TB Portable External Hard Drive was used;
- it has not been damaged by wear and tear, it has a lifespan of less than a year;
- it was formatted in APFS without encryption;
- there was one container inside the drive and one volume inside the container;
- when the issue occurred, the drive volume disappeared from the Finder and was grayed out in Disk Utility (the container and the device itself remained available);
- First Aid was getting a -69845 error on the volume, a -69716 error on the container;
- no problems were found when running First Aid on the device;
- almost all files were available for recovery or reconstruction using a third-party utility. Nevertheless, some files' names were lost, and the utility created a "Deleted or lost" folder - there were several corrupted photo libraries in it (the files were no bigger than several kilobytes, the message when trying to open: "The library "Photos Library.photoslibrary" could not be recognized."), though libraries were actually fully recovered;
- after erasing the container, the disk has been working fine.

Comment: Are you aware that during a shutdown, *all* running processes, including those that mount filesystems on things like external drives are sent a signal (`SIGKILL` or `SIGTERM`) that ends the process, flushes the unwritten data and *cleanly* unmounts all volumes?  All of this disconnection is wholly unnecessary.

Comment: Do you have references for the need to physically disconnect? I've never heard of that, nor seen it in a couple of decades of using Macs with external drives connected almost all the time.

Comment: @Allan, You're basing your reasoning on limited theoretical information about how macOS works, whereas my experience speaks for me, the fact that I KNOW what my drive sounds like during a proper shutdown - almost silent. When it shuts down when my Mac shuts down, there is an abrupt spinning break with a distinctive friction sound. What's more, other people have also encountered issues while rebooting a Mac with a drive plugged in: "I have the same problem. <...> Might be that it occurred after a reboot, I usually never reboot my Mac." Source: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695361

Comment: “…there is an abrupt spinning break with a distinctive friction sound. “ ***Your drive is in the process of failing; get that fixed!***  It’s not an issue related to startup/shutdown processes.  What you posted there is a *bug report.* If you want more details on my “theoretical info” go to Terminal and type `man shutdown`.

Comment: @gidds, I'm glad you have a serene experience with external drives on your Mac, but not everyone is so lucky. I'm not the only one who has had this issue after rebooting my Mac. And I believe that in the case of protecting the drive (especially HDDs) and information from damage, there is simply no better preventive measure than this. Read the thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695361

Comment: @Allan, I am definitely sure it is a bug, which is why I think you should not ignore the problem, but be aware of it, which is why I am writing about it as a rule about disk protection. This is a major system bug that we don't know when it will be fixed, or if it will be fixed at all (I doubt it). If you volunteer to check this on your drives, I promise that as soon as none of ten drives fail after ten times rebooting the Mac, I will remove this rule and breathe a sigh of relief. As for the bug report, I would appreciate it if you could let me know where I can commit the bug report, thank you.

Comment: This answer might get a better reception if you edited in some details on your year of manufacture / connection method / drive manufacturer. This is very much not my experience and we manage thousands and thousands of Macs with drives connected and then restart all the time remotely and we've noticed the opposite - moving the connection is far more likely to cause failure in our data / experience. I'm not saying you're totally wrong at this point, but do you have limited data / anecdotal evidence at this point? I'm glad you're sharing - that's one thing this site is great for

Comment: You additional details should really be in the question.  It now transpires that you have an issue with a particular disk. Maybe change the whole question to one more clearly about your Toshiba not working as expected.  I have a similar 3TB Toshiba which is working fine and has no problems with reboots.

Comment: @bmike, Thanks for the recommendations. I have added the information I have about my drive and the case. I don't deny that other users may have a different experience, but I have encountered this many times in my own experience (I only realized from the second time that the cause was unplanned disconnections caused by rebooting). As for the evidence, I didn't collect it. One can believe me, check it with a pre backed up disk, or ignore my advice at their own risk. With all due respect, I wrote the post to help other Mac users, not to prove anything to anyone.

Comment: @Gilby, Thanks for the suggestions and feedback about your Toshiba disk. If you have any ideas on how I can create a more specific and clear question/bug report on Stack Exchange about my Toshiba disk issue with macOS, please let me know. I'm open to any feedback or advice on how to better frame my post to provide the best possible help to other Mac users.

Comment: The issue with this question/answer is that you’re taking a *particular* bug involving a specific drive with a specific file system and conflating it across all devices regardless of filesystem and advising that everyone should follow a prescribed methodology when shutting down their computers when for a vast majority of people, it simply doesn’t apply.  Also, SE isn’t the venue for bug reports